# PHP - hacker rank - ransom check - extra space at the end of the string

Tags: php, arrays

I am working on a problem statement of hacker rank, the idea is that a kidnapper want to recreate a ransom note using a magazine, the input format is as below -

> 6 4
>   give me one grand today night
>   give one grand today

6 and 4 are the counts of words in magazine and ransom respectively, so I just need to check and return "Yes" if the ransom note can be re-created using the words in magazine, otherwise return "No".

My code is working fine as expected, but during two test cases the output is being printed wrong, and that is because of an extra space at the end of a key.

I am first taking the counts of the array values into another array, and checking the value by comparing the keys of ransom with magazine.

I've downloaded the test case and when I test it locally the result is No, that is because the last word in the magazine array is having an extra white space character.

Here's the search where you can see there is an extra space at the end of the string, and because of that the string is not getting matched and is returning output as "No". I've observed that is that last string in the array after counting the values.

Beneath that you have links to the inputs and expected output.

[image]

Test case 1:
I/P - https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/24432/input16.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1513762294&Signature=GoW9OnUfaKo3gwmM2X4L%2FpjQndM%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain

Expected O/P: Yes

```
<?php

$handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
fscanf($handle,"%d %d",$m,$n);
$magazine_temp = fgets($handle);
$magazine = explode(" ",$magazine_temp);
$ransom_temp = fgets($handle);
$ransom = explode(" ",$ransom_temp);

    $countRan = array_count_values($ransom);
    $countMag = array_count_values($magazine);

    if(count($countRan) > count($countMag)) {
        print "No";
        return;
    }

    foreach ($countRan as $key => $value){
        // exit if key not exists in $countMag array
        // or exit if value in $countRan[$key] greater than $countMag[$key]
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $countMag) || $value > $countMag[$key]) {
            print "No";
            return;
        }
    }
    print "Yes";
?>
```

Comment: Sounds like you are missing a [`trim()`](http://php.net/trim).

Comment: I tried using trim, but the same is making other test cases get failed. I was thinking of fetching the last element, from array and trim it, how can I achieve it? 
`end($countMag); $key = key($countMag); rtrim($key,"");` this doesn't seem to work

Comment: Not rtrim, trim(). see here https://3v4l.org/j5saW if you had looked in the manual of rtrim it would be obvious

Comment: The link in the question seems to be dead.  Can you provide a different (long-life) link?  I'd like to have a look at this question but I don't have access to all of the necessary information.

Comment: [Poke] I'd like to have a look at your seemingly unresolved question, but I don't have a way of testing because I cannot access the sample input.  Please update your question to provide all necessary details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure if I grasped this correctly but this seems to work OK. Perhaps the bit that you might find useful is the `array_map('trim',$data);` piece ~ that'll trim the trailing spaces.

```
$url='https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/24432/input16.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1513762294&Signature=GoW9OnUfaKo3gwmM2X4L%2FpjQndM%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain';
$data=file_get_contents( $url );


$pieces=preg_split( '@\n@', $data );
$lengths=$pieces[0];
list( $l1, $l2 )=explode(' ',$lengths );

$magazine=array_map('trim',explode( ' ', $pieces[1] ) );
$ransom=array_map('trim', explode( ' ', $pieces[2] ) );



if( count( $magazine )!=count( $ransom ) ){
    echo "No";
} else {
    $intersection=array_intersect( $ransom, $magazine );
    if( count( $intersection ) == count( $magazine ) && count( $intersection ) == count( $ransom ) ){
        echo 'Yes';
    } else { echo 'No'; }
}
```